# Animate CSS responsive stylesheet with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate, responsive-design

I have a responsive website which loads different some CSS from an external Stylesheet, responsive.css, depending on viewport size.

When the desired viewport changes these new CSS rules get loaded and the webpage adjusts accordingly, but I would like this transformation to be animated. Rather than everything just snapping into place. For instance, tablet portrait and tablet landscape have slightly different styles, so an animation effect here would be quite pleasant.

Basically, is there a simple way where I can just say `.animate('resonsive.css');` or am I just being delusional with that simplicity? If so could somebody explain to me how to go about doing this?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there a reason you have split the styles into different stylesheets?

Better would be to include all styles within one stylesheet and simply segregate those targeting different screen sizes with

```
@media  (min-width: XXXem) and (max-width: XXXem) {
    Put your styles in here.
}
```

You can then apply CSS transitions to the elements you want to animate:

```
elements to animate {
-webkit-transition:all .2s ease-in;  
-moz-transition:all .2s ease-in;  
-o-transition:all .2s ease-in;  
transition:all .2s ease-in;
}
```

Here is a pen as an example:
http://cdpn.io/cwbuf

Read here for more on transitions:
http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/transitions/

Comment: Ah yes, I have done it this for now as this is my first responsive website and keeping separate would stop me getting confused. I will do this once I'm ready to deploy. Thanks for the heads up :)

Comment: Ah, ok. I added a pen to demonstrate... just open it and resize to see the div respond. Keep in mind that this is progressive enhancement: i.e. will only work in browsers supporting CSS transitions. Much better than using jQuery, though (faster).

Comment: Sweet, I've kept things degrading gracefully, I'm at the stage of implementing some bells and whistles, it's nice knowing it can be accomplished in css3 as I've tried to make the website as accurate as possible with javascript turned off. Thanks for the advice, you now get a green tick. :D

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there isn't a simple 1 line solution to this.

You can achieve the effect you want by adding something like `transition: all 1s ease-in;` or just `transition: 1s ease-in;` to any element that you want to animate. That will basically animate any change in css properties for that particular element over 1 second.

Have a read of http://www.impressivewebs.com/css3-transition-all/ for more info about it.

Comment: Aha! This is the kind of thing advice I'm looking for, so it's all done in CSS3? Perfect, this is the kind of direction I was looking for, thank you. Here, have a green tick. :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery http://masonry.desandro.com/ plugin for that.

Resize their page to see what happens.

Comment: Yea, I've heard about the masonry plugin, I was hoping of doing something on my own though. Thanks for the tip.